# Why does last index of string array print nothing in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am curious why the last element in my array of 29 size is 27, and not 28? Why is there a blank space when I try to print out the object in the 28th place? `s` should be the last object in the 28th place no?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char strArray[] = { "Jonsnow from Game of Thrones" };
    int lastElem = sizeof(strArray);

    printf("%s\n", strArray);
    printf("Size of array is: %d\n", sizeof(strArray));
    printf("first array value: %c \n", strArray[0]);
    printf("last array value: %c \n", strArray[lastElem - 1]);
    printf("last array value: %c \n", strArray[lastElem - 2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Jonsnow from Game of Thrones
Size of array is: 29
first array value: J
last array value:
last array value: s
```

Comment: Because it is the null terminator

Comment: Are you sure it's not a duplicated question? So many answers tho...

Comment: Try printing its integer value: `printf("val '%c' = %d\n", strArray[lastElem-1], strArray[lastElem-1]);`

Comment: `sizeof`function calculate byte size of variable in your case for `strArray` **sizeof** will be `number of character + null character = 29` but `strlen(strArray) = 28`so basically in line `printf("last array value: %c \n", strArray[lastElem-1])`you want to access character at position `28` but last character should be at position `27` because index will start from `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lastElem-1 is reserved for the '\0' which the null terminator.

The null terminator prints nothing as it's a sentinel to signify the end of the string, since if there's no null terminator, just given some char array, it's unclear where the string ends.

Comment: *The null terminator prints nothing* not really. It **does** print but is stripped by the terminal driver. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

The last byte in a C string is the null terminator, a byte with a value of `0`, also written as `'\0'`. `strArray` is a `char` array initialized from a C string constant, its size is exactly that of the initializer, including the null byte, hence `strArray[lastElem-1]` is the null byte `'\0'`.

Outputting a null byte with `printf` `%c` format should work fine, a null byte being written to `stdout`, but it is possible that your terminal ignores such bytes and produces the output you posted. You can try and redirect the output of your program to a file and examine this file with a hex editor to see if indeed it contains a null byte before the newline.

I get the same behavior on my MacBook with OS/X:

```
chqrlie@mba1 ~/dev/stackoverflow > ./nullbyte
Jonsnow from Game of Thrones
Size of array is: 29
first array value: J
last array value:
last array value: s
```

But here is the binary dump of the program's output:

```
chqrlie@mba1 ~/dev/stackoverflow > ./nullbyte | od -bc
0000000   112 157 156 163 156 157 167 040 146 162 157 155 040 107 141 155
           J   o   n   s   n   o   w       f   r   o   m       G   a   m
0000020   145 040 157 146 040 124 150 162 157 156 145 163 012 123 151 172
           e       o   f       T   h   r   o   n   e   s  \n   S   i   z
0000040   145 040 157 146 040 141 162 162 141 171 040 151 163 072 040 062
           e       o   f       a   r   r   a   y       i   s   :       2
0000060   071 012 146 151 162 163 164 040 141 162 162 141 171 040 166 141
           9  \n   f   i   r   s   t       a   r   r   a   y       v   a
0000100   154 165 145 072 040 112 040 012 154 141 163 164 040 141 162 162
           l   u   e   :       J      \n   l   a   s   t       a   r   r
0000120   141 171 040 166 141 154 165 145 072 040 000 040 012 154 141 163
           a   y       v   a   l   u   e   :      \0      \n   l   a   s
0000140   164 040 141 162 162 141 171 040 166 141 154 165 145 072 040 163
           t       a   r   r   a   y       v   a   l   u   e   :       s
0000160   040 012
              \n
0000162
```

As you can see, the fourth line does have a null byte present between spaces.

Note also that there is bug in the program: `%d` may be inappropriate for an argument of type `size_t`. The C99 format is `%zu` but for portability to systems with poor C99 runtime support, I would recommend this:

```
printf("Size of array is: %lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(strArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize an array of `char []` with a string-literal enclosed in double quotes, what you aren't seeing is the null-terminator being added implicitly to the end of the string.  That's why the array has length 29 though your string literal only has 28 printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a `char` array with a string constant without giving a size to the array, the size of the array is the number of characters in the string constant, **plus 1 for the terminating null byte**.

So `strArray[lastElem-1]` has a value of 0, and printing that value as a character typically prints nothing.

If you were to use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`, you would get 28 and `strArray[lastElem-1]` would be `'s'`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in a C-String (a char-array) the last position is a null-termination: ‘\0‘ is used to end a C-string. Thus you will not get a result if you try to print out the last index. The last element of the actual String is thus the size of the array - 2, as you can see from your output.